# Powershell strange results with two "-Filter" conditions

Tags: powershell, filter

I want to exclude two words from my query, but I'm getting some strange results. To show this I use two description values that do not exist.

**First :**

```
(Get-ADUser -Filter {(description -like "*fffffffffff*") -or (description -like "*rrrrrrrrrr*")} -properties *).count
```

=> **no result** (it's ok)

**Then :**

```
(Get-ADUser -Filter {(description -notlike "*fffffffffff*") -and (description -notlike "*rrrrrrrrrr*")} -properties *).count
```

=> **300** (why ?!)

**And finally :**

```
(Get-ADUser -Filter * -properties *).count
```

=> **1090** - this result is OK (total number of users in AD)

Maybe with `where-object` pipe it will work, but I would to understand where is the trick.

Comment: Btw. avoid `-Properties "*"` in AD-queries that might return many users (like this). It's just a waste of time and processing. Specify the properties you need (except for the default properties). :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test this atm. but considering that `description -like "*"` returns users **with** a value in the `description`-attribute and `description -notlike "*"` returns only users **without** a value, I would guess that you have 300 users in the domain with a value (any value) in the `description`-attribute.

> Get all users with an e-mail attribute:
>
> ```
> Get-ADUser -filter 'email -like "*"'
> ```
>
> Get all entries without an e-mail attribute:
>
> ```
> Get-ADUser -Filter 'Email -notlike "*"'
> ```

Source: [about_ActiveDirectory_Filter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh531527(v=ws.10).aspx)

Try `(Get-ADUser -Filter { description -like "*" } -properties *).count` to verify.

```
#Has fffffffffff or rrrrrrr in description
(Get-ADUser -Filter {(description -like "*fffffffffff*") -or (description -like "*rrrrrrrrrr*")} -properties *).count
0

#Do not have fffffff or rrrrrr in description, but DOES have a description-value
(Get-ADUser -Filter {(description -notlike "*fffffffffff*") -and (description -notlike "*rrrrrrrrrr*")} -properties *).count
300

#Any user
(Get-ADUser -Filter * -properties *).count
1090
```

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking that code return all accounts, but no. It returns only accounts with a description)
`Get-ADUser -filter 'description -like "*"'`

But how can I see accounts who have not "\*fffffffffff\*" and not "\*rrrrrrrrrr\*" including no description ?

I know that using the "where" statement will work, but I was trying to do it with the -filter expression.

Comment: So just to verify, you got 300 using `description -like "*"`?

Comment: Here is (I edited my previous message)
`(Get-ADUser -Filter { description -like "*" } -properties *).count
=> 300
(Get-ADUser -Filter { description -notlike "*" } -properties *).count
=> 790`

Comment: Great. I learn something ever day. :-) What about `{((description -notlike "*fffffffffff*") -and (description -notlike "*rrrrrrrrrr*")) -and (description -like "*")}` ?

Comment: Thank you for your help !

Nope (return 300), because `(description -like "*")` will only return accounts with not empty description, and I want to return both :(

Comment: `{((description -notlike "*fffffffffff*") -and (description -notlike "*rrrrrrrrrr*")) -or (description -notlike "*")}`